# WordPress User Bookmarks Plugin - Collections

Tags: php, wordpress, bookmarks

I bought and Install "WordPress User Bookmarks (Standalone version)" So the problem is, this plugin have 1 default collection, by default, for each user but I need 3 or more default collections for each user I need to know how can I edit codes to add 3 or more collections by default.

THANKS ALL

Also I Attached API Documents here:

---

```
<?php

class wpb_api {

function __construct() {

}

/******************************************
Get first image in a post
******************************************/
function get_first_image($postid) {
    $post = get_post($postid);
    setup_postdata($post);
    $first_img = '';
    ob_start();
    ob_end_clean();
    $output = preg_match_all('/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i', $post->post_content, $matches);
    if (isset( $matches[1][0])) {
        $first_img = $matches[1][0];
    }
    if(isset($first_img) && !empty($first_img)) {
        return $first_img;
    }
}

/******************************************
Get thumbnail URL based on post ID
******************************************/
function post_thumb_url( $postid ) {
    $encoded = '';
    if (get_post_thumbnail_id( $postid ) != '') {
        $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $postid ), 'large' );
        $encoded = urlencode($image[0]);
    } elseif ( $this->get_first_image($postid) != '' ) {
        $encoded = urlencode( $this->get_first_image($postid) );
    } else {
        $encoded = urlencode ( wpb_url . 'img/placeholder.jpg' );
    }
    return $encoded;
}

/******************************************
Get post thumbnail image (size wise)
******************************************/
function post_thumb( $postid, $size=400 ) {
    $post_thumb_url = $this->post_thumb_url( $postid );
    if (isset($post_thumb_url)) {
        $cropped_thumb = wpb_url . "lib/timthumb.php?src=".$post_thumb_url."&amp;w=".$size."&amp;h=".$size."&amp;a=c&amp;q=100";
        $img = '<img src="'.$cropped_thumb.'" alt="" />';
        return $img;
    }
}

/* New collection */
function new_collection($name) {
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    $collections = $this->get_collections($user_id);
    $collections[] = array('label' => $name);
    update_user_meta($user_id, '_wpb_collections', $collections);
}

/* Remove a collection */
function hard_remove_collection($id){

    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    $collections = $this->get_collections($user_id);
    $bookmarks = $this->get_bookmarks( $user_id );

    // remove bookmarks
    foreach($collections[$id] as $k => $arr) {
        if ($k != 'label') {
            if (isset($bookmarks[$k])){
                unset($bookmarks[$k]);
            }
        }
    }

    // remove collection
    if ($id > 0){
        unset($collections[$id]);
    }

    update_user_meta($user_id, '_wpb_bookmarks', $bookmarks);
    update_user_meta($user_id, '_wpb_collections', $collections);
}

/* Soft-Remove a collection */
function soft_remove_collection($id){

    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    $collections = $this->get_collections($user_id);
    $bookmarks = $this->get_bookmarks( $user_id );

    // transfer bookmarks to default collection
    foreach($collections[$id] as $k => $arr) {
        if ($k != 'label') {
            $collections[0][$k] = 1;
        }
    }

    // remove collection
    if ($id > 0){
        unset($collections[$id]);
    }

    update_user_meta($user_id, '_wpb_bookmarks', $bookmarks);
    update_user_meta($user_id, '_wpb_collections', $collections);
}

/* Get bookmarks by collection */
function get_bookmarks_by_collection($id){
    $collections = $this->get_collections( get_current_user_id() );
    return $collections[$id];
}

function get_bookmarks_count_by_collection($id){
    $collections = $this->get_collections( get_current_user_id() );
    if ($id == 0){
        if (empty($collections[$id])){
            return 0;
        } else {
            return (int)count($collections[$id]);
        }
    } else {
        return (int)count($collections[$id])-1;
    }
}

/* print bookmarks */
function print_bookmarks($coll_id) {
    $output = '';

    $output .= '<div class="wpb-coll-count">';
    $output .= sprintf(__('%s Bookmarks in Collection','wpb'), $this->get_bookmarks_count_by_collection($coll_id));

    if ($coll_id != 0) { // default cannot be removed
    $output .= '<a href="#" class="wpb-bm-btn bookmarked wpb-remove-collection" data-undo="'.__('Undo','wpb').'" data-remove="'.__('Remove Collection','wpb').'">'.__('Remove Collection','wpb').'</a>';

    /* To hide a collection */
    $output .= '<div class="wpb-coll-remove">';
    $output .= __('Choose how do you want to remove this collection. This action cannot be undone!','wpb');
    $output .= '<div class="wpb-coll-remove-btns">';
    if ($this->get_bookmarks_count_by_collection($coll_id) > 0) {
    $output .= '<a href="#" class="wpb-bm-btn wpb-hard-remove" data-collection_id="'.$coll_id.'">'.__('Remove collection and all bookmarks in it','wpb').'</a>';
    $output .= '<a href="#" class="wpb-bm-btn secondary wpb-soft-remove" data-collection_id="'.$coll_id.'">'.__('Remove collection only','wpb').'</a>';
    } else {
    $output .= '<a href="#" class="wpb-bm-btn secondary wpb-hard-remove" data-collection_id="'.$coll_id.'">'.__('Remove collection','wpb').'</a>';
    }
    $output .= '</div>';
    $output .= '</div>';

    }

    $output .= '</div>';

    $bks = $this->get_bookmarks_by_collection( $coll_id );
    $results = 0;
    if (is_array($bks)){
    $bks = array_reverse($bks, true);
    foreach($bks as $id => $array) {
        if ($id != 'label') {
        $results++;
        if (get_post_status($id) == 'publish') { // active post

            $output .= '<div class="wpb-coll-item">';
            $output .= '<a href="#" class="wpb-coll-abs wpb-bm-btn secondary" data-post_id="'.$id.'" data-collection_id="'.$coll_id.'">'.__('Remove','wpb').'</a>';

            $output .= '<div class="uci-thumb"><a href="'.get_permalink($id).'">'.$this->post_thumb($id, 50).'</a></div>';

            $output .= '<div class="uci-content">';
            $output .= '<div class="uci-title"><a href="'.get_permalink($id).'">'. get_the_title($id) . '</a></div>';
            $output .= '<div class="uci-url"><a href="'.get_permalink($id).'">'.get_permalink($id).'</a></div>';
            $output .= '</div><div class="wpb-clear"></div>';

            $output .= '</div><div class="wpb-clear"></div>';

        } else {

            $output .= '<div class="wpb-coll-item">';
            $output .= '<a href="#" class="wpb-coll-abs wpb-bm-btn secondary" data-post_id="'.$id.'" data-collection_id="'.$coll_id.'">'.__('Remove','wpb').'</a>';

            $output .= '<div class="uci-thumb"></div>';

            $output .= '<div class="uci-content">';
            $output .= '<div class="uci-title">'.__('Content Removed','wpb').'</div>';
            $output .= '<div class="uci-url"></div>';
            $output .= '</div><div class="wpb-clear"></div>';

            $output .= '</div><div class="wpb-clear"></div>';

        }

        }
    }
    }

    if ($results == 0){
        $output .= '<div class="wpb-coll-item">';
        $output .= __('You did not add any content to this collection yet.','wpb');
        $output .= '<div class="wpb-clear"></div></div><div class="wpb-clear"></div>';
    }

    return $output;
}

/* Get collections for user */
function collection_options($default_collection, $post_id){
    $output = '';
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    $collections = $this->get_collections($user_id);
    $bookmarks = (array) get_user_meta($user_id, '_wpb_bookmarks', true);
    if (isset($bookmarks[$post_id])){
        $cur_collection = $bookmarks[$post_id];
    } else {
        $cur_collection = 0;
    }
    foreach($collections as $k => $v) {
        if (!isset($v['label'])) $v['label'] = $default_collection;
        $output .= '<option value="'.$k.'" '.selected($k, $cur_collection, 0).' >'.$v['label'];
        $output .= '</option>';
    }
    return $output;
}

/* Find collection ID */
function collection_id($post_id){
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    $bookmarks = (array) get_user_meta($user_id, '_wpb_bookmarks', true);
    if (isset($bookmarks[$post_id])){
        return $bookmarks[$post_id];
    }
}

/**
    Is post bookmarked
**/
function bookmarked($post_id){
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    $bookmarks = (array) get_user_meta($user_id, '_wpb_bookmarks', true);
    if (isset($bookmarks[$post_id])){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

/* Delete collection */
function delete_collection($collection_id, $user_id) {
    $array = $this->get_collections($user_id);
    unset($array[$collection_id]);
    update_user_meta($user_id, '_wpb_collections', $array);
}

/* Get collections */
function get_collections($user_id) {
    return (array)get_user_meta($user_id, '_wpb_collections', true);
}

/* Get bookmarks */
function get_bookmarks($user_id) {
    return (array)get_user_meta($user_id, '_wpb_bookmarks', true);
}

/* Count bookmarks */
function bookmarks_count($user_id) {
    $bookmarks = (array)get_user_meta($user_id, '_wpb_bookmarks', true);
    unset($bookmarks[0]);
    if (!empty($bookmarks) ){
        return count($bookmarks);
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

/* Get current page url */
function get_permalink(){
    global $post;
    if (is_home()){
        $permalink = home_url();
    } else {
        if (isset($post->ID)){
            $permalink = get_permalink($post->ID);
        } else {
            $permalink = '';
        }
    }
    return $permalink;
}

/**
    Display the bookmarks in
    organized collections
**/
function bookmarks( $args = array() ){
    global $post;
    $defaults = array(
        'default_collection' => wpb_get_option('default_collection'),
    );
    $args = wp_parse_args( $args, $defaults );
    extract( $args, EXTR_SKIP );

    /* output */
    $output = '';

    // logged in
    if (is_user_logged_in()){

    $output .= '<div class="wpb-coll">';

    $output .= '<div class="wpb-coll-list">';

    $collections = $this->get_collections( get_current_user_id() );
    $active_coll = 0;
    foreach($collections as $id => $array) {
        if (!isset($array['label'])) { $array['label'] = $default_collection; }
        if ($id == $active_coll) { $class = 'active'; } else { $class = ''; }
        $output .= '<a href="#collection_'.$id.'" data-collection_id="'.$id.'" class="'.$class.'">';
        if ($class == 'active'){
        $output .= '<i class="wpb-icon-caret-left"></i>';
        $output .= '<span class="wpb-coll-list-count wpb-coll-hide">'.$this->get_bookmarks_count_by_collection($id).'</span>';
        } else {
        $output .= '<i class="wpb-icon-caret-left wpb-coll-hide"></i>';
        $output .= '<span class="wpb-coll-list-count">'.$this->get_bookmarks_count_by_collection($id).'</span>';
        }
        $output .= $array['label'].'</a>';
    }

    $output .= '</div>';        
    $output .= '<div class="wpb-coll-body">';
    $output .= '<div class="wpb-coll-body-inner">';

    $output .= $this->print_bookmarks($coll_id = 0);

    $output .= '</div></div><div class="wpb-clear"></div>';

    $output .= '</div>';

    // guest
    } else {

        $output .= '<p>'.sprintf(__('You need to <a href="%s">login</a> or <a href="%s">register</a> to view and manage your bookmarks.','wpb'),wp_login_url( get_permalink() ), site_url('/wp-login.php?action=register&redirect_to=' . get_permalink())).'</p>';

    }

    return $output;
}

/**
    Bookmark: display the widget that allow
    bookmarks
**/
function bookmark( $args = array() ){
    global $post;
    $defaults = array(
        'width' => wpb_get_option('width'),
        'align' => wpb_get_option('align'),
        'inline' => wpb_get_option('inline'),
        'no_top_margin' => wpb_get_option('no_top_margin'),
        'no_bottom_margin' => wpb_get_option('no_bottom_margin'),
        'pct_gap' => wpb_get_option('pct_gap'),
        'px_gap' => wpb_get_option('px_gap'),
        'widgetized' => wpb_get_option('widgetized'),
        'remove_bookmark' => wpb_get_option('remove_bookmark'),
        'dialog_bookmarked' => wpb_get_option('dialog_bookmarked'),
        'dialog_unbookmarked' => wpb_get_option('dialog_unbookmarked'),
        'default_collection' => wpb_get_option('default_collection'),
        'add_to_collection' => wpb_get_option('add_to_collection'),
        'new_collection' => wpb_get_option('new_collection'),
        'new_collection_placeholder' => wpb_get_option('new_collection_placeholder'),
        'add_new_collection' => wpb_get_option('add_new_collection'),
    );
    $args = wp_parse_args( $args, $defaults );
    extract( $args, EXTR_SKIP );

    /* options */
    if (strstr($width, 'px')) { $px = 'px'; } else { $px = '%'; }
    if ($px == '%') {
        $btn_width = 50 - $pct_gap . $px;
    } else {
        $btn_width = ($width / 2 ) - $px_gap . $px;
    }
    if ($widgetized == 1){
        $btn_width = '100%';
    }

    /* output */
    $output = '';

    // logged in
    if (is_user_logged_in()){

    if (isset($post->ID)){
        $post_id = $post->ID;
    } else {
        $post_id = null;
    }

    $output .= '<div class="wpb-bm wpb-bm-nobottommargin-'.$no_bottom_margin.' wpb-bm-notopmargin-'.$no_top_margin.' wpb-bm-inline-'.$inline.' wpb-bm-'.$align.' wpb-bm-widgetized-'.(int)$widgetized.'" style="width:'.$width.' !important;" data-add_new_collection="'.$add_new_collection.'" data-default_collection="'.$default_collection.'" data-new_collection_placeholder="'.$new_collection_placeholder.'" data-dialog_unbookmarked="'.$dialog_unbookmarked.'" data-dialog_bookmarked="'.$dialog_bookmarked.'" data-add_to_collection="'.$add_to_collection.'" data-remove_bookmark="'.$remove_bookmark.'" data-post_id="'.$post_id.'">';

    $output .= '<div class="wpb-bm-inner">';

    /* collections list */
    $output .= '<div class="wpb-bm-list">';
    $output .= '<select class="chosen-select-collections" name="wpb_bm_collection" id="wpb_bm_collection" data-placeholder="">';
    $output .= $this->collection_options( $default_collection, $post_id );
    $output .= '</select>';
    $output .= '</div>';

    /* action buttons */
    $output .= '<div class="wpb-bm-act">';

    if ($this->bookmarked($post_id)) {
        $output .= '<input type="hidden" name="collection_id" id="collection_id" value="'.$this->collection_id($post_id).'" />';
        $output .= '<div class="wpb-bm-btn-contain" style="width:'.$btn_width.' !important;"><a href="#" class="wpb-bm-btn primary bookmarked" data-action="bookmark">'.$remove_bookmark.'</a></div>';
    } else {
        $output .= '<div class="wpb-bm-btn-contain" style="width:'.$btn_width.' !important;"><a href="#" class="wpb-bm-btn primary unbookmarked" data-action="bookmark">'.$add_to_collection.'</a></div>';
    }
    $output .= '<div class="wpb-bm-btn-contain bm-right" style="width:'.$btn_width.' !important;"><a href="#" class="wpb-bm-btn secondary" data-action="newcollection">'.$new_collection.'</a></div>';

    $output .= '</div><div class="wpb-clear"></div>';

    $output .= '</div>';
    $output .= '</div>';

    if (!$inline) {
        $output .= '<div class="wpb-clear"></div>';
    }

    // guest
    } else {

        $output .= '<p>'.sprintf(__('You need to <a href="%s">login</a> or <a href="%s">register</a> to bookmark/favorite this content.','wpb'),wp_login_url( get_permalink() ), site_url('/wp-login.php?action=register&redirect_to=' . get_permalink())).'</p>';

    }

    return $output;
}

}

$wpb = new wpb_api();
```